# Solr direct match search

Tags: solr

I'm trying to test the different features in Solr and I would like to create a basic text searcher that only returns direct matches. I have simple documents containing phrases:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "one blue car"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "two blue cars"
}]
```

My schema includes:

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="nameExact" type="text_exact" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="_version_" type="float" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

<copyField source="name" dest="nameExact"/>

<fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My solrconfig includes:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="df">name</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I would like to search for "one blue car" and receive the entry with id = 1
Is this the correct setup to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a field type for string. (i hope you have defined this)

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

The filed definition is correct.

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

You can search the same with simple query like

```
q=name:"one blue car"&rows=100&wt=json&indent=true
```

You don't need to define a new field nameExact and separate fieldType to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks this was the way to go :)